# single quote in database values breaks import

Tags: mysql, regex, notepad++

Hello and sorry I've seen alot of problems like this but no direct answer for me,

First let me say this is a WordPress problem the retards are not escaping single quotes when there saved in the database so I now have the problem that I have an exported database I have to restore but can't,

This is an Example of my Problem

```
INSERT INTO `demo` VALUES(1, 'wordpress\'s developers are stupid');
```

Now as for why WordPress doesn't run there database inserts though `mysql_real_escape_string` is beyond me but I'm using notepad++ to fix the issue so I need a REGEX way to keep the string and replace the ' mark out of the string

So I've managed to get one working that converts the HTML tags:

```
   Find: =\\\'([^']*)\\\'
   Replace: =\"\1\"
```

So I need to find '(quote open) \'(random quote) ',(quote close with , after for next value in query) or ');(quote close at end of query)

So I need to change the random quote to `&#39;`

For my file I'm getting a this exact error

```
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (787,0,'_transient_feed_9d5a2d683089079967601880d493887f','a:4:{s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:3:\"rss\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:4:\"\n \n\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:7:\"version\";s:3:\"2.0\";}}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:7:\"channel\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:83:\"\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:4:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:48:\"link:http://www.agressousergroup.co.uk/ - Google Blog Search\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:85:\"http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&q=link:http://www.agressousergroup.co.uk[...]

MySQL said: 

#1366 - Incorrect string value: '\x85 item...' for column 'option_value' at row 1
```

The really annoying thing is that when I search the script im using for "x85 item" there are no results (I'm using notepad++)

Exact Query:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (787,0,'_transient_feed_9d5a2d683089079967601880d493887f','a:4:{s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:3:\"rss\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:4:\"\n  \n\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:7:\"version\";s:3:\"2.0\";}}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:7:\"channel\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:83:\"\n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n  \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:4:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:48:\"link:http://www.agressousergroup.co.uk/ - Google Blog Search\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:85:\"http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&q=link:http://www.agressousergroup.co.uk/&tbm=blg&tbs=sbd:1\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:88:\"Results <b>1</b> - <b>10</b> of about <b>117</b> for <b>link:http://www.agressousergroup.co.uk/</b>.\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"item\";a:10:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:67:\"SCOM 2007 R2 Event Log Alerting and Monitoring for Azure <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:125:\"http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2011/08/19/scom-2007-r2-event-log-alerting-and-monitoring-for-azure-applications.aspx\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:543:\"For this first part of setting up rules, I am essentially following guidance which can be found on TechNet at <em>http</em>://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508734.aspx. To begin, we will launch <b>...</b> this series of documents. From the Actions pane on the far right, select the New <em>link</em>, and then from the popup menu, select the Custom Rule… item. <b>....</b> Below is my successful telnet session that was launched from the command line with the command telnet <em>localhost</em> 25. You can use anything for <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:53:\"Thoughts on ALM, Azure, and Agile by Walter Myers III\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:16:\"Walter Myers III\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Fri, 19 Aug 2011 01:02:14 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:1;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:73:\"HowTo install the Brother DCP-<b>7065DN</b> in a Linux network <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:91:\"http://bleedux.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/brother-dcp-7065dn-receiving-data-but-not-printing/\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:320:\"Result: none available for the DCP-<em>7065DN</em>. <b>...</b> emacs PathToTemporaryDir/usr/local/Brother/Printer/<em>DCP7065DN</em>/cupswrapper/<em>cupswrapperDCP7065DN</em>-2.0.4 <b>...</b> If you now return to <em>http</em>://<em>localhost</em>:631/ <b>...</b> <em>Link</em> the files in the following way: <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:17:\"The Bleeding Edge\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:12:\"M. Marschall\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Mon, 01 Aug 2011 00:33:11 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:2;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:74:\"Outlook Web Access Web Administration Tool - The page cannot be <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:112:\"http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/141270-outlook-web-access-web-administration-tool-the-page-cannot-be-found\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:551:\"I downloaded the Outlook Web Access Web Administration Tool from: <em>http</em>://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx? <b>...</b> FamilyID=<em>4bbe7065</em>-a04e-43ca-8220-859212411e10&amp;displaylang=en <b>...</b> server itself, it has been a while since had a 2003 server, but I recall similiar issues. I don&#39;t have a fix, but I do remember always RDP&#39;ing into the server and accessing the Web admin tool locally. Here is a helpful <em>link</em>. <em>http</em>://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508837(EXCHG.65).aspx <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:20:\"Spiceworks Community\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:7:\"Reg1145\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Thu, 26 May 2011 14:45:38 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:3;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:70:\"Transmittal Letter No. 661 Volume I To: Heads of Government <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:46:\"http://www.fms.treas.gov/tfm/vol1/v1p4c210.pdf\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:520:\"<em>http</em>://www.paymentaccuracy. gov used to post specified improper payment information submitted by agencies, consist- ent with the requirements of. Executive Order 13520, § 2.(b). This official Web site also is used to collect from the public <b>...</b> changes, and <em>links</em> to additional resources and information otherwise available on the. Internet. The timelines for agencies to submit required improper payments information for posting on the PaymentAccuracy.gov. Web site are discussed in <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:16:\"FMS Publications\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:7:\"unknown\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Thu, 14 Apr 2011 19:34:56 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:4;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:21:\"????? - ????\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:41:\"http://toos-iran.blogfa.com/post-171.aspx\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:781:\"?????? ???? d-<em>link</em> 300t ???? adsl ??????? (---) 6295. <b>....</b> ??? <em>localhost</em> ????? 127.0.0.1 ????? 6421. <b>....</b> ??? ???? ???? ? ???? ?? ???? ???? ?????? (TP-<em>Link</em> TD-W8901G) 6541. <b>....</b> ??????? ???????? ??? ????? ?? <em>http</em>://www.demonoid.com/ 6830. <b>....</b> <em>7065</em>. ?? chat ???? 7066. ?????? ???? ???? ADSL 7067. ???? ???? ?? ??????? wireless ???? 7068. ????? ????? ?? ??? ????? ??? ???? ???? 7069. ????? ??????? ???? ????? ?? ??? 2003 7070. ???? ???? ??????? 7071. ???? ** ?????? 7072. ?????? <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:10:\"?????\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:9:\"toos-iran\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Wed, 23 Mar 2011 07:00:00 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:5;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:52:\"Learning Ruby: Expert Advice for Advanced Developers\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:50:\"http://mashable.com/2011/02/02/advanced-ruby-code/\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:324:\"<em>http</em>://<em>localhost</em>:9292/to_a -&gt; 123. # <em>http</em>://<em>localhost</em>:9292/pop -&gt; 3. # <em>http</em>://<em>localhost</em>:9292/shift -&gt; 1. # Implementations in other languages (thanks guys!): # Node.js: <em>https</em>://gist.github.com/700995. # Groovy: https://gist.github.com/702337 <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:9:\"Mashable!\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:12:\"Jolie O\'Dell\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Wed, 02 Feb 2011 13:40:03 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:6;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:69:\"Sending Email Alert for Application Current State « Middleware Magic\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:43:\"http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=7042\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:535:\"If you see an Empty Classpath even after running the “setWLSEnv.sh” then please refer to the Note mentioned at Step3) in the Following post: <em>http</em>://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?page_id=1492 Step-5) Now run the WLST Script in the same <b>...</b> total.number.of.servers=3. server.name.1=AdminServer server.url.1=t3://<em>localhost</em>:7001. server.name.2=MS-1 server.url.2=t3://<em>localhost</em>:5001. server.name.3=MS-2 server.url.3=t3://<em>localhost</em>:6001. # Check Server State At following interval in <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:16:\"Middleware Magic\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:11:\"Ravish Mody\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Thu, 07 Jul 2011 12:38:30 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:7;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:54:\"Server Kurulumu : Hatalar , Sorunlar , Bilmedikleriniz\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:89:\"http://pvp-serverler.forumclan.com/t2019-server-kurulumu-hatalar-sorunlar-bilmedikleriniz\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:644:\"Host:HamachiIp.100// <em>Localhost</em> // 192.168.2.100. Port:3306[Mysql Port] ID:Root PW:123456[Degistirmediyseniz] <b>....</b> pc . give_item2 ( &quot;<em>7065</em>&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;11835&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;12645&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;13025&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;14105&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;15089&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;16105&quot; , 1 ) pc . give_item2 ( &quot;17105&quot; , 1 ) say_reward ( &quot;Du erhielst Super Eline Saglk . Schamiset!&quot; ) end <b>...</b> Kullanici profilini gör <em>http</em>://pvp-serverler.forumclan.com <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:71:\"Metin2 PVP Serverler l Private Serverler l Knight Private Serverler l :\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:10:\"MrLeqandry\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Thu, 06 Jan 2011 15:59:17 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:8;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:51:\"CARA SPYWARE MENGINFEKSI KOMPUTER « Lombok_Creck84\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:74:\"http://creck84.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/cara-spyware-menginfeksi-komputer/\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:522:\"Seorang penyerang remote bisa membuat <em>link</em> URL dibuat menggunakan Objek Data Tag akan dieksekusi di web browser&#39;s korban dalam konteks keamanan dari situs hosting, setelah <em>link</em> diklik. Para penyerang memanfaatkan <b>...</b> <em>HTTP</em> / 1.1 200 OK Tanggal: Mon, 18 April 2005 12: 27: 30 GMTServer: Apache / 1.3.33 (Unix) mod_deflate / 1.0.21 Koneksi: tutup Transfer - Encoding: chunked Content - Type: application / HTA script &lt; bahasa =&gt; JScript try { . Diri moveTo (5000, 5000); <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:14:\"Lombok_Creck84\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:14:\"Lombok_Creck84\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Tue, 28 Dec 2010 04:51:11 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}i:9;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:47:\"\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n    \";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"child\";a:2:{s:0:\"\";a:3:{s:5:\"title\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:42:\"???????? ? telnet - ZABBIX Forums\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"link\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:50:\"http://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=20387\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"description\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:553:\"<em>http</em>://www.zabbix.com/documentation/...l/config/items <b>...</b> [root@<em>localhost</em> ~]# /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -X &quot;host 192.168.1.52 and tcp port 10010&quot; tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on eth0, <em>link</em> -type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes <b>...</b> command&gt;&quot;.fo 0x00a0: 7220 696e 666f 726d 6174 696f 6e20 6f6e r.information.on 0x00b0: 2061 2073 <em>7065</em> 6369 6669 6320 636f 6d6d .a.specific.comm 0x00c0: 616e 642e 0a0d and. <b>...</b>\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}s:32:\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\";a:3:{s:9:\"publisher\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:13:\"ZABBIX Forums\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:7:\"creator\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:5:\"angro\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:4:\"date\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:29:\"Mon, 27 Dec 2010 23:11:53 GMT\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}}}s:36:\"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/\";a:3:{s:12:\"totalResults\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:3:\"117\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:10:\"startIndex\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:1:\"1\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:12:\"itemsPerPage\";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"data\";s:2:\"10\";s:7:\"attribs\";a:0:{}s:8:\"xml_base\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"xml_base_explicit\";b:0;s:8:\"xml_lang\";s:0:\"\";}}}}}}}}}}}}s:4:\"type\";i:128;s:7:\"headers\";a:7:{s:12:\"content-type\";s:28:\"text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1\";s:4:\"date\";s:29:\"Tue, 11 Oct 2011 09:59:27 GMT\";s:7:\"expires\";s:2:\"-1\";s:13:\"cache-control\";s:18:\"private, max-age=0\";s:10:\"set-cookie\";a:2:{i:0;s:143:\"PREF=ID=f20c4b1c78116086:FF=0:TM=1318327167:LM=1318327168:S=JmwTN04g_cBBkXlQ; expires=Thu, 10-Oct-2013 09:59:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com\";i:1;s:212:\"NID=51=kumBg-YqiVjIylrlQZnAp1IHv6-PAK1TIMAXdUBv4d9njuL-S5g35y0ZJYHQQxUJrc3rG8i2vRNHvkb_Ydpag_xqTuIEihrf2G0LM2c6pTZ6imb8lozQWVJOKQoEV4gm; expires=Wed, 11-Apr-2012 09:59:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly\";}s:6:\"server\";s:3:\"gws\";s:16:\"x-xss-protection\";s:13:\"1; mode=block\";}s:5:\"build\";s:14:\"20090627192103\";}','no');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly off-topic but:

Surely the problem is not that the database doesn't escape quotes.  It is perfectly valid to have unescaped content in the database, because otherwise you coupling the use of the data in your DB to a particular presentation layer (HTML)...

It is the responsibility of the presentation layer to ensure that all content is displayed safe.  If you are re-importing data to the same application and it still does output escaping, then if you change the quote `'` into `&#39;`, would the logic in the program escape the output to:

```
wordpress&amp;#39;s developers are stupid
```

The INSERT statement above is already escaped (after all, the backslash escapes the quote character) and according to the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html), `wordpress\'s` is the result of putting `wordpress's` through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

So, if you really want to change the quotes, as they are already escaped, you can probably do a straight replace of `\'` to `&quot;`, but I suspect that you may run into other issues.

EDIT (based on updated post):

I believe you've may have run into a character encoding problem.  Based on your input line, I think the problem stems from:

```
select the Custom Rule… item
```

the `…` character may not be recognised in the character set (certainly when I pasted your input into my editor, it changed to a black box.  Check that your file encoding is correct, is it UTF-8 (or whatever MySQL expects) and not been mangled in a file transfer or something.

Comment: for some reason this is not the case though i have tried in MySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin and Navicat Lite none of these can import it just gives an error about something being unexpected (and by some thing i mean the first term it finds out of the ' E.G in the case above it would be `s ` as its not a MySQL function

Comment: Can you use `mysql` from the command line and do: `mysql> source scriptfile.sql`

Comment: No unforgivable this is going to a corp networked server we have no access to the terminal(CMD) system for the server and i could use my local install of mysql and connect to the server but i don't think the on site admins would be quite happy with me

Comment: If your MySQL login has permissions to do the inserts, then connecting using the mysql client is no different than connecting through MySQL Workbench, or have I missed something?

Comment: I know that you know that does not stop the monkeys incharge of our IT kicking of coz i'm uisng a Command Line tool they think i might damage the server or some thing who knows thats the problem with IT Departments separated from a Web Team our manager is pulling us to AWS soon anyways so i wont have this problem

Comment: @MartinBarker: I've only just noticed your edits, see my edit.

Comment: WOOOT thanks for pointing that out for some reason the wordpress database is using ISO-8859-1 so when there exported into UFT-8 there failing to convert properly the error i was getting was giving me the HEX code for the symbol, if you could just outline that and i will mark it as answer